# phpMyAdmin configuration

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was trying to install phpmyadmin and i keep running into this error and i tried selecting port 80 but the error comes back again, how do i solve this error? please help.

```
mysql: [ERROR] mysql: Empty value for 'port' specified . Your options      
  │ are:                                                                       
  │  * abort - Causes the operation to fail; you will need to downgrade,       
  │    reinstall, reconfigure this package, or otherwise manually intervene    
  │    to continue using it. This will usually also impact your ability to     
  │    install other packages until the installation failure is resolved.      
  │  * retry - Prompts once more with all the configuration questions          
  │    (including ones you may have missed due to the debconf priority         
  │    setting) and makes another attempt at performing the operation.         
  │  * retry (skip questions) - Immediately attempts the operation again,      
  │    skipping all questions. This is normally useful only if you have        
  │    solved the underlying problem since the time the error occurred.        
  │  * ignore - Continues the operation ignoring dbconfig-common errors.       
  │    This will usually leave this package without a functional database.
```

Comment: Could you provide some detail how you try install phpmyadmin? From packages, from sources? Do you have working MySQL server?

Comment: yes i have a working mysql server and I am installing from sources

Comment: Is there a **specific reason** why you choose to use sources for the installation, rather than install directly from the repository which will be automatically configured and usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All required information about details for installation you have on docs page from phpmyadmin: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html
If you not need the newest version you can install it from ubuntu repository, for example as described here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04