# Cannot install phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: software-installation, phpmyadmin, 20.10

I've found many threats of this problem but any worked. I did the solution given in this but it didn't worked
[phpMyAdmin configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033096/phpmyadmin-configuration)

I am trying to install phpmyadmin, this is my config:
[image]

The package phpmyadmin must have a database installed and configured before be used... Do you want to configure the database with dbconfig-common?

[image]

Connection method for the MySQL database of phpmyadmin

[image]

MySQL Database server name for phpmyadmin

[image]

Port for the MySQL service

[image]

[image]

MySQL Database name for phpmyadmin

[image]

MySQL username for phpmyadmin

[image]

Give the name of the account that this package shall use for administrative tasks. This user will be used to create new database users.
It's often MySQL root.
Database administrator username:
(The result is the same using 'root' as user)

But I get this error
[image]

An error occurred while installing the database:
Your options are:
Abort.
Retry.
Retry without questions.
Omit.

I see that the error is that the access was denied, but in any place it's asked for an password